# One key in a dictionary. Need the 4th value of that key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary. I need to access the 4th value of the key.

Here is a small example:

```
Foo ={JFK: ['Airport',2433,-24322,'Dollar','America']}
print (Foo.values ())
```

What do I do in order to access  the value `Dollar`?

Comment: You can use a simple indexing `Foo[JFK][3] `

Comment: `Foo[Foo.keys()[0]][3]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: that won't work, Python 3, so `dict.keys()` is a *view*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you're right! How about `Foo[next(iter(Foo.keys()))][3]`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: why not do that with `Foo.values()` instead of `Foo.keys()`? At any rate, it's ugly as sin.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: too true. I was just having some fun is all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the value of the key 'JFK', you should apply:

```
Foo['JFK']
```

Since the value of 'JFK' is an array and you want to access the 4th element of that array:

```
Foo['JFK'][3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array within a dictionary, so the value returned will be the array.

This code gets the value at key 'JFK' and then returns element 4 ('Dollar') from the value.

```
Foo['JFK'][3]
```